# Is this relational not equal to expression well defined?

Tags: c++

Consider a class `Foo` of which `foo` is an instance.

`Foo` has a function `calculate()` that changes an internal member for which `watermark()` is the "getter", and returns something with the same type as that internal member.

Is the expression

```
foo.calculate() != foo.watermark()
```

well-defined. That is, must `calculate()` happen before `watermark()` is called?

In order words, is the evaluation order strictly `foo.calculate()`, followed by `foo.watermark()` followed by `!=`?

Comment: There are no sequential point between both, the order of evaluation is unspecified.

Comment: clear duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no sequential point between both, the order of evaluation is unspecified.

You have to force sequence as for example:

```
const auto& res = foo.calculate();
res != foo.watermark();
```

Answer (score 3):

**The C++ Standard(ISO/IEC 14882:2014) say's :**

> Sequenced before is an asymmetric, transitive, pair-wise relation
>   between evaluations executed by a single thread, which induces a
>   partial order among those evaluations. Given any two evaluations A and
>   B, if A is sequenced before B, then the execution of A shall precede
>   the execution of B. **If A is not sequenced before B and B is not
>   sequenced before A, then A and B are unsequenced. Evaluations A and
>   B are indeterminately sequenced when either A is sequenced before B or
>   B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified which.**

Do not allow the same scalar object to appear in side effects or value computations in both halves of an unsequenced or indeterminately sequenced operation.

Reference link [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/EXP50-CPP.+Do+not+depend+on+the+order+of+evaluation+for+side+effects).

Answer (score 0):

It may help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.